# Android Studio. Objects ouside of viewport are not drawn?

Tags: android, xml

I've created a few objects off-screen using translation so that I can animate them coming in.
The problem is that they are not being drawn.

I tried putting the objects halfway in, and when I move it in, only that half exists.
Is there an attribute I can just check to let them be drawn off-screen?